# facing problem in updating a index value of the state inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have a state,

```
const [weekdays, setWeekdays] = useState([{
    day: 'S',
    fullName: 'Sunday',
    select: false
},
{
    day: 'M',
    fullName: 'Monday',
    select: false
},
{
    day: 'T',
    fullName: 'Tuesday',
    select: false
},
{
    day: 'W',
    fullName: 'Wednesday',
    select: false
},
{
    day: 'T',
    fullName: 'Thursday',
    select: false
},
{
    day: 'F',
    fullName: 'Friday',
    select: false
},
{
    day: 'S',
    fullName: 'Saturday',
    select: false
    }])
```

I have newData,

```
const newData=['Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday']
```

I want to update that weekDays state to select: true for those days which are present in newData and others remains same.

I am trying to findout the indexes which have the fullName as the newData,then targeting that particular index I can change a single property,but don't know how to do that.

```
useEffect(() => {
    {
        if (data?.length > 0) {
            
            setWeekdays(weekdays=>([...weekdays,data]))
            
        }
    }
}, [data]);
```

If any one knows the answer then suggest me,How to achive this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by mapping over the `weekdays` and checking if the `weekday` fullName is in the data array. If in the array, update the `select` to `true` and return the new object. Else just return the `weekday`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  {
    if (data?.length > 0) {
      setWeekdays((prevWeekdays) => {
        const newWeekdays = prevWeekdays.map((weekday) => {
          if (data.includes(weekday.fullName)) {
            return {
              ...weekday,
              select: true,
            };
          }
          return weekday;
        });
        return newWeekdays;
      });
    }
  }
}, [data]);
```